# how to loop promises (nextPageToken)?

Tags: javascript

I need to cycle, but I need the value of the previous promise (nextPageToken)

I dont want repeat code

my code is this:

```
function load () {

    search_this_q = "cats";
    search (search_this_q)

    // loop here
    .then (function (result) {
        console.log ("thenb");
        return next_Page_Search (result.nextPageToken, search_this_q);
    })
    .then (function (result) {
        console.log ("thenc");
        return next_Page_Search (result.nextPageToken, search_this_q);
    })
    .then (function (result) {
        console.log ("thend");
        return next_Page_Search (result.nextPageToken, search_this_q);
    })
    // loop here

    .then (function (result) {
        console.log (result)
    })
}
```

Comment: does `next_Page_Search` return a promise or just a value? Also which previous `nextPageToken` do you need to re-use? `b,c,d`?

Comment: return promise, i need use  (result, result.nextPageToken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you could use recursion for this. Something like:

```js
function search(q) {
    console.log(q)
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve({ nextPageToken: q + 1 })
        }, 100)
    })
}


function load() {

    function loop(query, callsTodo) {
        return search(query).then(function (result) {
            return callsTodo === 0 ? 
                result :
                loop(result.nextPageToken, callsTodo - 1)
        })
    }

    return loop("cats", 3)
}

load().then(function (res) {
    return console.log(res)
})
```

That could be converted to a normal loop with variables in an outer scope, but it's easier to reason about scope/state like this.